# file_get_contents('php://input') not working. Empty - NULL

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I having this problem for the last 12 hours, i read about 50 articles, 50 questions here, i can't fix it. I will be more precise, i want others get the solution too.

**The problem:** I have a hosting account in namech****, and a local server. Linux there and Xampp Windows here, this only works in my local server.

```
test.php:

<?php    
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);
        var_dump($data);
?>
```

The post request is:

```
POST /test.php HTTP/1.1
Host: myweb.io
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 77

{
  "test": "product/created",
  "other": "https://google.com/"
}
```

I use REQBIN for test the POST request.

**This is the response in my hosting:**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 03 May 2020 17:04:33 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.4.5
Content-Encoding: gzip
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

NULL
```

**This is the correct response on my local enviroment using XAMPP**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 03 May 2020 17:15:19 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.41 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1c PHP/7.4.3
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.4.3
Content-Length: 94
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

Array
(
    [test] => product/created
    [other] => https://google.com/
)
```

**Things i've tried:**

- Set the allow_url_fopen to 1, or 0.
- Downgrade PHP versión (Tried 7.1,2,3,4)
- Uninstall SSL Certificate
- Millions of things in PHP.INI
- Removing htaccess
- Removing some php modules / extensions
  UPDATE:
- The file is individual, cheched that the function is only execute one time
- I check if there are no redirections. (Htaccess, cPanel settings)

Comment: If you do several things at the same time, you can't know what's failing. What does `var_dump(file_get_contents("php://input"));` print?

Comment: Please have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18866571/receive-json-post-with-php

Comment: I'd also recommend to refrain from trying random stuff you find in Google unless they include a sensible explanation that links it to your problem. I understand your frustration, but these random changes can easily break things.

Comment: "It is worth pointing out that if you use json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input")) (as others have mentioned), this will fail if the string is not valid JSON." - @xtrasimplicity
And the response from your server returns gzipped data: "Content-Encoding: gzip"

Comment: OP HERE: 

@ÁlvaroGonzález  var_dump(file_get_contents("php://input")); output: string(0) ""

Comment: OP HERE:

 @SalimIbrogimov i think its a valid json data, isn't?

Comment: A common reason you'd be missing POST data due to an environmental issue would be an HTTP redirect - are you sure that's not happening on your hosting?

Comment: `Content-Length: 77` looks like too much (even with Windows line feeds it should be around 70). Do you really have that much data (e.g. empty lines or trailing spaces)?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález sorry, i paste the lenght from other .

Comment: @iainn i think i have no redirects. No htaccess, no ssl. No redirects in cPanel.

Comment: One more silly test: does it get through if you replace `https://google.com` with anything else, e.g. `kittens`?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález yes its working, it output the whole google site.

Comment: I mean that, in your request, remove `https://google.com` and type a simple text that isn't a URL. That's to discard there's a security filter removing requests that contain URLs. Also, an additional diagnostic you can do is to upload a regular HTML form to your site and submit from there; that's to figure out if HTTP referrer matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix it, don't know how, but i think the solution was:
Delete my htaccess completely, no redirections (http to https).
Dont test with reqbin, test it with php pure code, or PostMan.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue; apparently an HTTP Redirect (e.g 301 to https) was prohibiting the data from being redirected along.

Make sure you have no redirects.

Answer (score 1):

Believe it or not:

Changing:
**RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,L,R]**

to

**RewriteRule ^ %1 [NC,L,R]**

and then back to

**RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,L,R]**

And similarly
**RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ /$1.php [NC,L]**

to

**RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]**

and then back to

**RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ /$1.php [NC,L]**

Appeared to sort it out!

Answer (score 0):

this is just happened to my clients website.

My client used Nginx and redirect if its contain www. eg:

```
https://www.example.com
```

to

```
https://example.com
```

Mycode:

```
$notifications = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"),TRUE);
```

If Its hitted by www.
The result of `$notifications` is `NULL`

but if hits by using second link (without www)

The `$notifications` is contains exactly the inputed.

The solution is:
Change the access URL. In my case, change webhook URL.

Answer (score -1):

I also had this problem, and I realized that my address was `http://` instead of `https://`.

Now I have something with `file_get_contents("php://input")`

I hope this will solve your problem.